# Creating new List of objects in Java throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, list

I have short question because I can't understand my mistake.

I have a collections:

```
      List<ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO> managedFilesAuthorityDTOs = filesAuthorityRepository.findAll().stream()
        .map(ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then I'm creating new list

```
List<ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO> outputFileList = null;
```

and I would like to iterate for *managedFilesAuthorityDTOs* and assign some object to *outputFileList*.

Here's my loop:

```
 for (ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO dto : managedFilesAuthorityDTOs) {
        outputFileList.add(dto);
    }
```

And I still getting **NullPointerException** because my outputFileList is equals null. What I am doing wrong that I can't create new List?

Comment: "then I'm creating new list" No, you're declaring a variable - and assigning it the value `null`. Create a list: `List<ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO> outputFileList = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: `List<ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO> outputFileList = null;` this is not creating new list, this is declaring variable `outputFileList`

Comment: Thanks for answers. I thought that it has to be stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you're not creating a new list, this is how you do it:

```
List<ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO> outputFileList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a list, you are setting it to `null`.
Should be:

```
List<ManagedFilesAuthorityDTO> outputFileList = new ArrayList<>();
```